# $http angularjs data, in a cache ? but why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I use $http to check a date in a js file. When i do a console.log of entire data, it's same as the online version, but, with this code :

```
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urlDataDistant, cache: false, timeout: 1500}).
        success(function(data, status) {

            var dataD = paramsField.params[0].data.date;
            console.log(dataD);

(...)
```

this data (dataD) seems cached, and it's not same as the true online data when i refresh my page ! What's wrong ?

Comment: What is that `paramsField`?

Comment: Did you expect server and client date to be different? A code snippet of your server code will be helpful to us.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your browser network monitor, is your browser sending requests to the server? What is the status of those requests? If it's 304, then the result is cached in the browser (which has nothing to do with the $http service).
You would need to use a cache killer in your request, or to handle the expiry of the response in the server side.

Comment: It's return a 200. cache killer ? the "false" do nothing ? oO

Comment: Cache killer is when you send in your url a random parameter (or a timestamp) to make it differ from previous request (e.g. http://server/myReq?randomParam=99898323). But if you say you get 200 then it's not relevant.
Like Larry said - a code snippet would be good

Comment: I made a plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/0YtwyWUawDVgaYHywZin When i see this code on my browser, it's show me an old value, and a same value for the two tests

Comment: There a problem with the service you invoke. It returns a java script with the following content:
    var paramsField = {
     "params" : [
      {
       "data" : {
        "date" : "2010-03-09"
       }
      }
      ]
    }
 I guess you meant to return a json.